# Using BWToolkit Framework APIs

Tags: iphone, macos, interface-builder, app-store, bwtoolkit

I received some helpful info from *NSGod* that informed me that using BWToolkit would possibly be rejected from Apple for using private APIs. The only object I used from BWToolkit was the `BWSplitView` (I needed the ability to `toggleCollapse` - like iTunes' Ping Sidebar - slides in and out). If anyone has any info on this possibly not working for the app store, or an alternative, it would be **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a fairly detailed discussion of this subject here: http://bwalkin.lighthouseapp.com/projects/36323-bwtoolkit/tickets/72

The gist is "It doesn't matter what you use in IB as long as you use the unchanged framework you will get rejected.", but removing the `BWTokenField` code from the framework is enough to get approval.

Comment: @Zakman: You need to remove the private API offending headers.  They are: `NSTokenAttachment.h` and `NSTokenAttachmentCell.h`.

Answer (score 1):

ByteProject has released a new version of the BWtoolkit without any private api.

They removed BWTokenField, which uses NSTokenAttachmentCell and this is private API3

more info here : http://byteproject.net/

Comment: Thanks WebMixer!! I'm glad somebody threw that together makes me feel more confident before I wait 10 days for a response from Apple